# Php SQL inner join?

Tags: php, sql

So I'm making a portfolio website where I can post and edit blogs.

I'm making the blog edit page and I'm having trouble with combining two table together.

The **first** table is for the blogs and the **second** table holds all the different blog categories.

Here's how I'm getting the blog posts:

```
$qStr = "SELECT post_title, post_content, post_description, post_active, category_id  FROM posts WHERE post_id = {$post_id}";
```

Here's how I'm getting the blog categories:

```
$qStr = "SELECT category_name FROM categories WHERE category_id = {$category_id}";
```

So in my edit blog post page I have a dropdown box that I need to show which category that blog post is in, and be able to change it. I have a category_id in my blog table. My question is how do I get the dropdown to show which category the post is under?

Right now my drop down code looks like this (note: Right now I'm just populating the dropdown with all the categories)

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="categorySelect" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Category</label>
     <div class="col-lg-3">
          <select class="form-control" id="categorySelect">
                <?php
                     foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                         echo("<option>{$cat['category_name']}</option>");   
                     }
                 ?>
           </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ``if ($cat['category_name'] == $current_category) { ... output `selected` attribute for <option>``, basically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the selected attribute for select (option) element, something like this:

```
<?php
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
       if ($cat['category_name'] == $category_of_your_post)
           echo "<option selected=\"selected\">{$cat['category_name']}</option>"; 
       else  
           echo "<option>{$cat['category_name']}</option>"; 
    }
?>
```

BTW, I think that you have the wrong queries (if I understood correctly your question). Basically you need to retrieve the category_id of your post and perform an equality question against the array of categories:

```
$qStrBlog = "SELECT post_title, post_content, post_description, post_active, category_id  FROM posts WHERE post_id = {$post_id}";
$qStrCat = "SELECT category_id, category_name FROM categories";
```

And then:

```
<?php
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
       if ($cat['category_id'] == $blog_data['category_id'])
           echo "<option selected=\"selected\">{$cat['category_name']}</option>"; 
       else  
           echo "<option>{$cat['category_name']}</option>"; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Add a `selected` attribute with an if-condition in the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    echo '<option';
    if ($cat['category_id'] == $post['category_id']) echo ' selected';
    echo '>'.$cat['category_name'].'</option>';
}
```

Or use an `INNER JOIN` on the post `SELECT` query:

```
$qStr = "SELECT p.post_title, p.post_content, p.post_description, p.post_active, p.category_id, c.category_name FROM posts INNER JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = p.category_id WHERE post_id = {$post_id}";
```

and throw the first `option` element as the "default currently selected" option:

```
      <select class="form-control" id="categorySelect">
            <option value="<?= $post['category_id'] ?>"><?= $post['category_name'] ?> (current)</option>
            <?php
                 foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                     echo("<option>{$cat['category_name']}</option>");   
                 }
             ?>
       </select>
```

I've made the assumption that you've correctly loaded your result from the first `SELECT` query into `$post`. Note that if it's possible to *not* set a Category to a Post, you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead and wrap the first `option` element output contingent on `$post['category_id']` not being empty.